# toggleClass in jquery dosent work when i use id selector in Css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm new at jQuery and I have a problem that when I use ID selector in CSS then my jQuery code doesn't work.

Here is HTML:

```
<body>    
    <div id="fm">
    </div>
</body>
```

Here is JavaScript Code:

```
$(function () {
    $("#fm").click(function () {
        $(this).toggleClass("cm");
    });
});
```

This CSS is OK and it works:

```
body>div{ 
    height:100px;
    background-color:blue;
    transition:all ease 0.5s;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:100px;
    right:0;
    z-index:1000;
}
```

But if I use `#fm` in CSS selector it doesn't work. I think it may be because of cascading behavior but I don't know how to fix it.

Here is the CSS which doesn't work:

```
#fm{ 
    height:100px;
    background-color:blue;
    transition:all ease 0.5s;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    bottom:100px;
    right:0;
    z-index:1000;
    border:1px solid black;
}
```

And this is cm class

```
.cm {
    background-color:red;
    height:150px;
}
```

I appreciate if you help

Comment: It is because of [css specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) not because of jQuery

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tdeyw4v1/1/ - the rule `#fm`(id-selector) is more specific than the class rule(`.fm`) so the styles in the id rule will override the class rule... so you can combine the class rule and id rule to make it work like `#fm.cs`

Comment: thank you again. I'm new in SO and I don't know how to accept your help. but I appreciate if you tell me how I can thank you by voting or marking any chekmark again thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```
#fm.cm
```

for your cm rule. This way, the ID doesn't override the class

Comment: Would you care to accept the answer then, so this topic will be solved?

Comment: Yes, It solved and I don't know how to thank Stack Overflow Team and also who helped me. Really Thank you

Comment: as you say ,yes I'm new in SO and I really appreciate your guidance.i didn't know how to accept it, but i think i should mark the Checkmark to the green right? again thank you .

Comment: No problem at all, thank you and best of luck coding :)

Answer (score 2):

`toggleClass` is working, but the `css` properties are not applied.

You need to use `!important` to override proeperties.

```
.cm {
    background-color:red !important;
    height:150px;
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/tusharj/ecojmyje/

Answer (score 2):

**Id have high priority in css** 
so your `.cm` class be override with id `#fm`

Use `!important` only work in the context

```
.cm
{
    background-color:red !imporatnt;
    height:150px;
}
```